# How to use swipe on different objects

Tags: android, gesture

I'd like to use the swipe(onFling) feature of android gestures. I have some adjacent pictures to
chancge into an other picture, in case of swiping.(Just like i demonstrated on the picture)
It should work regardless, which direction the player swipe his/her finger. 
Could you give me any link? Or any idea which components should i use?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your gesture appears to apply the premise that it must:

Gesture must include all adjacent views.

Gesture has a direct linear begginning and end

Gesture is a single movement

Gesture does not conflict with other similar gestures

You might want to read on "MotionEvent", and the onTouch listener for views.

A single flag `private static View beganOn;` on the parent class (I am supposing an Activity). Then:

```
public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m){
    if(beganOn!=null){
        begaOn = v; 
        return;
    } else {
        // Where the view Tag, is an Integer to state what number it is in the sequence.
        doSelectionOfViews(beganOn.getTag(),v.getTag());
        begaOn = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override the onfling() method of the Gesture Detector. You will be able to get the Swipe direction Under this. Now take two counters for both direction and increment it(i.e count++) in the Right/left swipe and vice versa. Below I am posting the code by which you will be able to create that circular indicator. Whichever you want to make highlighted, You need to pass the index only.

```
public void updateIndicator(int currentPage) {
    image_indicator.removeAllViews();
    DotsScrollBar.createDotScrollBar(this, image_indicator, currentPage, 5);
}
```

Here image_indicator is an linear layout defined in xml.

```
public static class DotsScrollBar 
{
    LinearLayout main_image_holder;
    public static void createDotScrollBar(Context context,
            LinearLayout main_holder, int selectedPage, int count) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ImageView dot = null;
            dot = new ImageView(context);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            vp.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 8);
            dot.setLayoutParams(vp);
            if (i == selectedPage) {
                try 
                {
                    dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.page_hint_pre);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                }
            } else 
            {
                    dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.page_hint_def);
            }
            main_holder.addView(dot);
        }
        main_holder.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Pass the index in the upDateIndicator() method to make that particular incator highlighted.